# [Toyota avalon 1995]How to disable the seat belt chime?

Tags: toyota, seat-belt, avalon

So my mom has a Toyota Avalon 1995 and it's been having problem with the seat belt chime. I would say the chime stays on all the time even after the car is locked, the chime is also on when the car is off as well. I've checked and removed any heavy items on the seats just make sure they don't trigger the chime. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is the seatbelt warning? It shouldn't chime when the car is off and locked. Does it turn off if you put the seatbelts connected? If it is really the seatbel chime, the problem is electrical and you should get it fixed. Disabling the chime would just be a poor workaround.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the seatbelt warning because if you put your seat belt on, the the chime stops.

Comment: In my experience seat belt warnings do not normally come on if the ignition is NOT turned to on position. So, if your car thinks the ignition is on when it is not on tells me that there is maybe an underlying cause to fix and it may cause other unexpected events if not diagnosed (I highly recommend you to get checked properly). But I found this, maybe works for your car: http://www.justanswer.com/toyota/7emzv-toyota-avalon-turn-off-seat-belt-warning-buzze.html

Answer (score 3):

Key on engine off, check to see if there's power at the gauge fuse. If there's power at the gauge fuse disconnect the ignition switch and recheck for power at the gauge fuse. If you have power at the gauge fuse with the ignition switch disconnected, there's a short in the integration relay or a short to power between the switch and relay.

If you wanted to disable the driver seat belt chime, ground the red/yellow wire at the buckle switch. This may not pass a safety inspection though.

Comment: A great answer as always @Ben !